# Close sign graphics bug?

Tags: graphics, system-monitor

Just out of curiosity:
When I open the GNOME System Monitor, there is always a [Black spot on the "close" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7mLq.png) of the window. It doesn't disappear when I drag the window around or close and relaunch the application. It does not affect the functionality by any means, but I wondered how it comes that I observe this phenomenon always and exclusively for this application.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS,
System Monitor version 3.32.1-3-g0ea89b4922

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the close buttons broken on snap apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206868/why-are-the-close-buttons-broken-on-snap-apps) Really you have two options here: ¹st switch GTK theme from GNOME Tweaks to one of *Ubuntu-mono-dark, Ubuntu-mono-light, Yaru* or ²nd - switch to traditional desktop environment as [MATE DE as in Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).